# Expose Objc private headers to Swift in a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, testing

I need to mix Swift and Objective-C code inside a static library in iOS. I have created `module.modulemap` file and included the `Private` module there. I can also import the private module without any error message, but still the compiler throws an error when I try to reference the private class with `Use of unresolved identifier 'PrivateClass'`

**UsePrivateClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import StaticLib.Private

class UsePrivateClass {
    func printPublicClass() {
        PublicClass().print()
    }
    func printPrivateClass() {
        PrivateClass().print()
    }
}
```

**module.modulemap**

```
module StaticLib {
    export *

    explicit module Private {
        header "PrivateClass.h"
    }
}
```

I have already set `DEFINE_MODULES` to `YES` and `MODULEMAP_FILE` to the `module.modulemap` file. Probably missing something related to copying the modulemap file to the right destination or `PrivateClass.h` header file, but not sure what step is missing.

Created a sample project [here](https://github.com/maniramezan/StaticLibObjcSwiftSample).

Comment: Why not use a bridging header? So much less work.

Comment: @bsod Bridging header is for public headers and is accessible from outside of the framework. Also, it helps with readability by explicitly defining some headers under private header.

Comment: @liquid There are two ways to link C code to your Swift project:
1. Bridging-Header.h is ONLY for Applications and Unit Tests
2. Module map and header files are for frameworks